# Adobe flex as client with node.js

Tags: flex3, adobe, node.js, long-polling, server-push

I would like to use Adobe Flex to make a client and node.js to make a server for long polling. I am trying to develop a chat application in Flex.

Can any one suggest me how I can accomplish this?

Comment: I don't know much about the Adobe Flex stuff, but why do you want to create long polling server with this technology when it supports two-way communication?

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at (source code of) Socket.io [client](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO) and [server](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node) modules which are using Adobe Flash Socket as one of it's transport options.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly there are two ways to approach this:

1. Direct TCP using a combination of `flash.net.Socket` (Flash) and `net.Server` (node.js).
2. HTTP-based polling using a combination of `flash.net.URLLoader` (Flash) and `http.Server` (node.js).

It depends on your requirements.